# How to open telegram bot from Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open an telegram bot from Flutter app. How can I do it?

`Text('Join @SomeBot first, to get app results in Telegram!')`

How to make an opening by onTap text?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve problem with [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin

```
onPressed: () => launch(
                            "https://t.me/SomeBot",
                            forceSafariVC: false)
```